# No space between columns in awk output

Tags: awk

I am trying to print 2 column output using awk. I need to separate them out with a space. In this example below the first column value is '1' and the 2nd column is '1['. As seen in the output the two values are merged together. I am not able to print a space in between. The -vOFS flag does not seem to help. I am also printing just the last line of a cmd output in this awk statement.

In addition, I would also like to get rid of the '[' in the 2nd column output ('1['). So it's left with the '1' only. How exactly do I do that?

awk command:
sudo iblinkinfo | awk -vOFS=' ' 'NR==1; END{print $11 $12}'

awk'd Output I get:

`CA: MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox Technologies:
11[`

awk'd Output I want:

`1 1`

Original cmd output: (the last line starts with "CA: MT..."). Although first column output (with a $1) is the hex value 0xe41d2d0300e29e01. I would like to print the 11th, and 12th columns; which are 1   1[  (towards the end)

```
           1   34[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
           1   35[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
           1   36[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
CA: MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox Technologies:
      0xe41d2d0300e29e01      2    1[  ] ==( 4X          10.0 Gbps Active/  LinkUp)==>       1    1[  ] "Infiniscale-IV Mellanox Technologies" ( )
```

Comment: Tried with `{print $11 " " $12}` as well. But no luck

Comment: Please add output of `sudo iblinkinfo` and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Edited original post. Thank you @Cyrus

Comment: `print $11, $12`. What you have concatenates the variables into a single string, and thus doesn't put `OFS` between them.

Comment: Of course `printf` allows you to be very explicit about what you want the output to look like. Not sure why but hat option often seems overlooked in `awk`.

Comment: the `{print $11, $12}` worked! Thanks @Shawn. Is there a way to get rid of the '[' from the $12 output?

Comment: Here's a sample of what to do, `echo "[abc" | awk '{sub(/\[/,""); print $0}'`. Good luck.

Comment: Read a couple of awk examples as you're thrashing trying anything to make it work when it's really extremely simple and well covered in many examples and the man page. Setting `OFS=''` makes zero sense when you're trying to get a space between fields, `{print $11, $12}` won't work given that setting either, and there's no way that `{print $11 " " $12}'` did not produce a space between fields. You're printing a line with `NR==1` and then saying the output of doing so is unexpected. There are other issues with your script too and it can't do what you say it does given the sample input you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
           1   34[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
           1   35[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
           1   36[  ] ==(                Down/ Polling)==>             [  ] "" ( )
CA: MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox Technologies:
      0xe41d2d0300e29e01      2    1[  ] ==( 4X          10.0 Gbps Active/  LinkUp)==>       1    1[  ] "Infiniscale-IV Mellanox Technologies" ( )

$ awk 'END{print $11, $12+0}' file
1 1
```

The above relies on undefined behavior since the values of $0, $1, etc. in the END section are undefined by the POSIX standard but it'll work in GNU awk as you're using.

Comment: Yup, precisely! Thank you @Ed!